# is there any way to hide and redirect url by using rewrite rule?

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite

[Edited]
Hi 
There were lot of example to do similier what what i am trying to achive but it seems I am not understanding them properly, so asking for help. Please dont close this as duplicate ,

I have wordpess installed as primary website like this 
https://www.example.com/

apache configuration is like this

> ```
>     #ServerName www.example.com
>     ServerName example.com
>     ServerAdmin example.com
>     ServerAlias www.example.com
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/web
>     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
>     SSLEngine on
>
>     SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate/example.com/mydomain.crt
>     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certificate/example.com/mydomain.key
>     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certificate/example.com/mydomain.ca-bundle
>     <Directory /var/www/html/example/web>
>             AllowOverride All
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>             #AuthType Basic
>             #AuthName "Restricted Content"
>             #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
>             # Require valid-user </Directory>
> ```

Now i need to place 3 laravel project inside the web directory

```
> mydomain
>  - web (wordpress)
>    - en  ( Laravel project)
>    - bn  (laravel project)
>    - demo (laravel project)
```

now when i type like this it opens.as its php laravel project.

```
https://example.com/demo/public/
https://example.com/demo/public/home
https://example.com/demo/public/login

https://example.com/en/public/ 
https://example.com/bn/public/
```

However, I want to rewrite the rules such a way that  when some one type

```
https://example.com/demo/ -> it will provide data from   https://example.com/demo/public/    but url will be https://example.come/demo
https://example.com/bn/ -> it will provide data from  https://example.com/bn/public/ but url will be https://example.com/bn

https://example.com/en/ -> it will provide data from  https://example.com/en/public/ but url will be https://example.com/en
```

so all the pages after /public/* will be /demo/*  or /bn/* or /en/*

I have edited  .httaccess under /web/demo/ with bellow
ref :
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/wordpress-and-laravel-on-subfolder?page=1

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but when i type
https://example.com/demo/

its gives 404 which comming from laravel.

any help will be appreciate.

Comment: In your apache config you're showing the document root for example.com as  /var/www/html/example/web but then you've put the en,bn and demo directories next to web not in web, so the only site that's going to work is the Wordpress site. If you move those into web, I'm not sure how you'd then get Wordpress to ignore those subdirectories and let each laravel directory be it's own project. This would be much easier if you could use a subdomain for each of the laravel projects - is that out of the question?

Comment: Looks like this guy tried to go down this route and found lots of security issues with exposing the laravel .env files, because they're in the Wordpress public directory https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/wordpress-and-laravel-on-subfolder?page=1

Comment: @coedycode , Thanks , if  i follow that one, and i place demo, en, bn under web directory and put a .httaccess with rewrite rule as 
"<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
"
now is give me 404, so its going inside the public , but does not get other pages,

Comment: @coedycode , i have edit the question to reflect the solution from laracasts.com solution but i am still having problem

Comment: I don't use apache enough these days to be able to help I'm afraid. With Nginx it's possible to create a location block for your subdirectory path, and then within that location block you can give it it's own document root, so there'd be no need for a redirect rule, but I don't know if you can do that with apache directory blocks.